# if true is returned from javascript fire textchange event of same textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a textbox...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateOfPoroposal" runat="server" 
             CssClass="form-control" 
             OnKeydown ="javascript:return Validate(this);" 
             AutoPostBack="True"
             OnTextChanged="txtDateOfPoroposal_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox>
```

and a javascript function...

```
function Validate(obj) {
    var id = obj.id,
    value = obj.value;

    if (value == "") {
        /*some code here*/
        return false;
    } else {
        /*some code here*/
        return true;
    }
}
```

also, i have textchange function.....

```
protected void txtDateOfPoroposal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*some code here*/
}
```

I want to check validation first. If data is invalid then stop the postback event else after validation, I want to do postback. From my code, in both valid and invald case postback method is blocked. Please give me the solution...

Comment: `onchange="return Validate(this);"`

Comment: I have tried this too. Stil it does not work.